# In Enterprise Architect, can I export the structured specification of an element's scenario into a report?

Tags: documentation, report, enterprise-architect, scenarios

For each model element, there is the option in EA 10 to create `internal requirements`, `constraints` and `scenarios`. All of them end up in reports if you use the pre-defined `Basic Template`.
However, if you select "`structured specification`" instead of the default "`description`" text field for a `scenario`, then I end up with the steps of the structured specification being ignored in the report output.

How can I have them included in reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create your own reporting template. This may seem a bit daunting first time out and the template editor is pretty ornery, but luckily you can use an existing template as a starting point.

Hit F8 to bring up the Generate Documentation dialog, then select the Templates tab. Click New, specify a name and select a template you like to be copied. Don't bother with a template group, and leave the fragment checkbox unchecked.

In the editor, scroll down about halfway (assuming you selected to copy the Basic template) and locate the yellow `scenario >` tag.

Now in the checkbox tree on the left, scroll down do Package - Element - Scenario. Note that Scenario is checked, but Structured Scenarios is not. Check it.

In the editor, note the new `structured scenarios >` tag. Remove the right-click-to-insert text, then right-click and select Insert Field, then State etc.

It's more than a little fiddly, but if the Basic template is good enough to begin with you should be able to add the structured scenarios with a minimum of effort.

For more information, see the help file under Reporting - RTF Documents. Note that the individual fields aren't listed in the help file, you need to open up the template editor to see what specific information you can extract to your report.

Comment: I had already feared that it would not work without messing with the quirky template editor ;) Thanks, I'll try it out.